# Freemarker sort_by built-in issue

Tags: sorting, smarty, freemarker, built-in

Why do I have error on assign list sortered to the variable **sorting_itens** ? Once I have the property **category** in that object?

```
<#if title.getSiblings()?has_content>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <#assign itens = title.getSiblings() />
            <#assign sorting_itens = itens?sort_by("category") />
            <#list  sorting_itens as cur_title>     

                <#assign curr_category = cur_title.category.getData() />
                 ${curr_category}
            </#list>
        </ul>
    </div>          
</#if>
```

Comment: Including the error message would be useful.

Comment: "?sort_by(...) failed at sequence index 0: Values used for sorting must be numbers, strings, date/times or booleans."

Comment: Well, it says you exactly what's the problem: the `category` property is neither string, number, boolean, nor date/time (`java.util.Date`). None of these classes has a `getData()` method used to assign the `curr_category` variable few lines later. See the [sort built-in documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_sort).

Comment: Ok. I Agree. But it works: `<#if title.getSiblings()?has_content>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <#assign itens = title.getSiblings() />
            <#list itens as cur_title>     

                <#assign curr_category = cur_title.category.getData() />
                <li> ${curr_category}</li>
            </#list>
        </ul>
    </div>          
</#if>`

Comment: There is no reason it shouldn't - the problem is you're trying to sort the `itens` sequence (list) using an unsortable property (`category`).